# how do i use jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, django, django-views

How do i use `jquery autocomplete`? will you please help me ? thank you

UPDATE: I have written following view. Which works just fine without `ajax`. Now I want to integrate with `ajax`. I tired alot. But found no luck. I need your help. Thank you guys

## UPDATED views.py

```
def search(request):
errors = []
if 'q' in request.GET:
    q = request.GET['q']
    if not q:
        errors.append('Enter a search term.')
    else:

        categories = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0]
        languages = categories.language.all()

        movies = Movie.objects.filter(title__istartswith=q,language__in=languages)
        results = [ x.title for x in movies ]
        json = simplejson.dumps(results)
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/json")
```

## my form

```
<form action="/search/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" id ="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

UPDATE3: When I use following ajax function. It worked. Its displaying the data in `terminal`. But the problem is that its not showing list of movies in input field.

[image]d

## my ajax

```
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#q").autocomplete("/search/");  
});
    </script>
```

UPDATE 4: I've just changed the code. Now its displaying the contents in one line. Here is screenshot.
[image]

UPDATE 5: When I use this `return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="plan/text")` it worked. but the problem is same (all contents in one line). If i use `return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/json")` It does not work.

Comment: You start [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and keep reading until you have a specific question for us to answer.

Comment: "I've following example which is working fine." - Then what exactly is the problem?  Is there something you need help with?

Comment: Be nice. The OP is clearly trying if he's got the example working and a view. They just need a bit of help gluing it together. It's tricky the first time.

Comment: Can you show what you've written for the AJAX?

Comment: @U-DON I've not written. I'm new to ajax. I'm reading.

Comment: @U-DON Code Updated. Please help

Comment: You'd be done in no time using this fantastic app: https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 'q' as the get string, but the jquery autocomplete widget expects it to be called 'term'. You need to make the following change at the start of your view:

```
if 'term' in request.GET:
    q = request.GET['term']
    if not q:
        errors.append('Enter a search term.')
    ...
```

Edit: The next part of the answer was added before the OP updated their question and json encoded the results.

You can't just return a queryset of movies -- it has to be in a format that the autocomplete widget can understand. The easiest thing is to return a list of names (the same as in example you tried with programming languages. The end of your view should look something like this:

```
# import at the top of your views.py
from django.utils import simplejson
...
movies = Movie.objects.filter(title__istartswith=q,language__in=languages)
results = [ x.title for x in movies ] # this is good, you didn't need to comment it out!
# now encode the results as json, and return them
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(results), mimetype="application/json")
```

See how you get on with that, and leave a comment if you're still having trouble.

Comment: thank you for reply. I've updated view. I tried but now its not displaying contents in field. But in terminal it worked. What's the problem? I'm missing something? thank you

Comment: I think the problem now is that you are using `q` as the search parameter and not `term`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Mime type application/json should not cause any problems. Just to double check -- have you tried using `term` instead of `q`?

Comment: I tried with `term` its not working. 'q' is just working fine.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't spot what the problem is. I hope you manage to get it working.

Comment: I follow this url http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete. It worked. And you are right `I think the problem now is that you are using q as the search parameter and not term` thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to write your own Ajax, you can use this [tutorial](http://lethain.com/using-jquery-django-autocomplete-fields/). This is the way that i got Auto-Complete to work. If you have any problems making this work post in the comments.